# meaningless SELECT result after running myisamchk --sort-records

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
`parameters` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`num` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`val1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`val2` int(10) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ref` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`ref`) USING BTREE,
KEY `parameters` (`parameters`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=79092001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

there are 1170 different "date", and around 67000 different "parameters", each couple (date, parameters) is unique.

I'm trying to speed up a simple SELECT:

```
SELECT parameters, sum(val1) from mytable where parameters=(one random value)
```

I've indexed "parameters". the request takes around 8 seconds to return.

I tested "myisamchk --sort-records" to sort records according to my "parameters" index.

the results looked great at first, requests are running in 0.0x seconds.

however, when checking result values proper, I realize there's a big issue, in the case of

```
SELECT parameters, sum(val1) from mytable where parameters=10
```

the result I get is:

```
parameters= 10522 (!!!)
sum(val1)= 0
```

and it's the same story for all different values of parameters in the request, the result return has the parameters field not corresponding at all...

I can't understand what could have happened.

---

more information: I tried this, and it returned the proper parameters (=10 in this case)

```
SELECT val1 from mytable IGNORE INDEX(parameters) WHERE parameters=10;
```

that makes me think that the index is messed up. I haven't read anything about re-indexing after sorting the rows, but it could make sense. is it documented anywhere ?

---

I subsequently dropped the index and recreated it, it solved the problem, but it doesn't explain it. additionally, my request is now taking as much time as before (up to 8s), is there a way to make this myisamchk sorting of data work the way I intend it, with the associated gain in speed ?

Comment: What would be expected result? Have you tried running query without `sum(val1)` part, does it run normal?

Comment: expected result, regardless of the sum(val1), would be to have "parameters=10", as requested in the WHERE clause, no ? when running without the sum(val1), I get a list of parameters from 10522 to 11690... really don't get it !

Comment: rebuilt the indexes with myisamchk -rq, didn't help so far. will next try to drop my index altogether and recreate it.

Comment: Well, seems like just incorrect database functioning. Since it functioned normally (I presume) before you've created index, I guess it somehow related to it. Indded try first to remove index and verify that DB is functioning normally again.

Comment: dropping the index and recreating it solved the issue, but now my request is taking as much time as before (up to 8s).

Answer (score 2):

Run `myisamchk --sort-records` again. After that run a `CHECK TABLE mytable` and see what it tells you. MyISAM is not very stable, so it is possible that the index is f**ed up if it has a hickup during the sorting.

If the index is corrupt, this should show and you can run `REPAIR TABLE mytable`. This will fix the index. See if you query is slow again or if it is faster now.

If all this does not help, you have a few more options:

1. If it is possible, insert rows already ordered by `parameters`
2. Create partitions:
   `CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ... )
   PARTITION BY HASH(parameters)
   PARTITIONS 10;`
   This should also greatly increase query times.

Comment: did all this twice, with no positive result... inserting rows already ordered could be possible, but a massive pain. I tested partitions with no good result neither. I have just added a big chunk of RAM, will try all things again now.